# User log in method in Java SOAP Web Service Application isn't working

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap, authentication

I'm trying to create a Web Service Application with Java in NetBeans. At this point I have to validate a user during login. User's credentials are stored in a MySQL database. DBConnection.getConnection() handles the connection with the database and it works correctly, although the method itself isn't working.

```
@WebMethod
public  boolean userLogIn (@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) throws SQLException  {

        Connection C = DBConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement PS = C.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password =?'");
        PS.setString(1, username); 
        PS.setString(2, password);            
        ResultSet RS = PS.executeQuery(); 

        if (RS.next())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

When I test the overall service I get this notice:

Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL http://my-computer.local:8080/webApp/webWS?WSDL

Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security

Could anyone suggest me how to correct it, to make the method works? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Almost anything could be wrong here. What are you testing with?

Comment: I'm just trying to create a school project. It's not a real life application. At this point I'm developing a SOAP web service in Java. The above method was wrong. For anyone who might find it useful, I'm posting a working log in method:

Answer (score 0):

This is a working log in method. It's not intended to be used in a real life application.

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "user")
public  User getUser (@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password)  {
    User user = new User();
    Password password1 = new Password ( password );
    try {
    Connection C = DBConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement PS = C.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
    PS.setString(1, username);
    PS.setString(2, Password.toSHA1());
    ResultSet RS = PS.executeQuery();

    while(RS.next()){
        if (RS.getString("username").equals(username) & RS.getString("password").equals(Password.toSHA1())) {
            user.setId(RS.getInt("id"));
            user.setUsername(RS.getString("username"));
            user.setPassword(RS.getString("password"));
            user.setName(RS.getString("name"));
            user.setSurname(RS.getString("surname"));
            user.setEmail(RS.getString("email"));
            user.setSex(RS.getString("sex"));
            user.setBirthday(RS.getString("birthday"));
            // ... other atributes
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return user;
}
```